# PHP allow only certain file uploads and also allow a user to PICK more than 1 file at a time to upload

Tags: php, types, multi-select

I somewhat have the coding, but I am missing this part.  The following PHP only allows gif, jpeg, jpg, doc, and pdf files to upload.  I have a max file size of no more than 5 megs.  Currently the coding is working as I wanted it to, WITH and exception.  I want to user to be able to PICK lets say 5, 6,  or 7 files at a time and then press the upload button 1 time.  I thought what I could do was just copy the input type='file' name='file_upload'> 5 times..that does work, but when I attempt to press the upload button, it waits a few seconds, and then pops up with my error code 'An error ocurred when uploading.'

If someone can assist, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am sure the coding could be much cleaner, but as you can see I am pretty new (like many) to php.

Thanks In Advance
Tony

HTML CODING:

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='../edocs.php'>
<input type='file' name='file_upload'><br>
<input type='submit' value="Upload" ><br><input type="reset" >



<?php
if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0){
die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type']!= 'image/gif')
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type']!= 'image/jpeg')
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type']!= 'image/jpg')
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type']!= 'application/msword')
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type']!= 'application/pdf'){
die('Unsupported filetype uploaded.  You need to change your file type
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try like this, it will work.

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>

    <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
            $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
            $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                ?>
                    <p>File #<?= $i+1 ?>:</p>
                    <p>
                        Name: <?= $myFile["name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Temporary file: <?= $myFile["tmp_name"][$i] ?><br>
                        Type: <?= $myFile["type"][$i] ?><br>
                        Size: <?= $myFile["size"][$i] ?><br>
                        Error: <?= $myFile["error"][$i] ?><br>
                    </p>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Or you can try http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Comment: I am sorry, this should have been scored a 2.  Problem with this coding is that its allowing for ANY type of file to be uploaded.  We cant have that due to .exe, .zip, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First change this

`multiple` attribute for file and name of the file as array.

```
<input type='file' name='file_upload[]' multiple><br>
                                     ^   ^// this will allow the user to select multiple files.
```

Then for `$_FILES` use `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename)
{
    $temp="path to upload the file";
    $tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count];
    $count=$count + 1;
    $temp=$temp.basename($filename);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp,$temp);
    $temp='';
    $tmp='';
}
```

Refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: This coding is GOOD.  The ability to only load the specific types of files I want to allow, and it also DOES allow for multiple PICKING of files.  But it only uploads the LAST file selected.  It will not upload all files.  For example, I chose 5 files: a jpg, a jpeg, a gif, a doc and a pdf (these are the only files allowed) but it only uploaded to my server, the last file that was picked.  Any further suggestions.